# How do I edit a password hash in visual studio lightswitch

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I've been writing apps for years now, but I've just recently been tasked with writing a very simple Lightswitch app to act as an internal tool for our dev team to edit the dev database on the web app we are currently building.

Part of the app needs to edit the user table, and be able to add/edit users in the database, and thus needs to be able to at least write an encrypted hash in the DB.

Problem is I'm using an external blowfish implementation to provide the hashes and salts for the passwords, and not any of the built in stuff.

So my question is this, how in any of the inputs I have on the screens I design, can I accept a plain string, then have my custom encryption saved in the database, I thought a computed property might have been what I needed but it's not.

I'm using lightswitch under visual studio 2013 enterprise in the C# language with .NET 4.5 as the base line and SqlServer as the back end data store.

Cheers
Shawty

Comment: Are you using the HTML or Silverlight LightSwitch client? Also, when viewing a previously entered value, do you still need to be able to view the unencrypted plain text?

Comment: It's a desktop / silverlight client chris.  I'm not bothered if I can see new value or not, but the folks using it are very new to this stuff, so simply adding a plain text passwd into the password field on the details, then having them press save and knowing that the password has been encrypted on it's way to the DB is enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a weekend of playing (You just never get chance to do things like this in the office :-) ) I came up with the following solution that seems to work.

In my case the encryption library I was using is "CryptSharp" [Crypt Sharp Home Page](http://www.zer7.com/software/cryptsharp), but because I'm creating a desktop client using silverlight, cryptsharp wouldn't install due to it needing a full .NET runtime.

This lead me to start investigating what I had access to at the data tier of the application:

[image]

After reading a few blog posts and some more MSDN, I figured out that I could hook an updating function.

More specifically, if you add custom code to the data tier, you get an "Updating" (and others) for each of your data object models, and thus (After adding CryptSharp via NuGet), I ended up with:

```
   partial void Users_Updating(User entity)
    {
        string encryptedPassword = "";
        string encryptedSalt = "";

        GenerateEncryptedPasswordAndSalt(entity.Password, out encryptedPassword, out encryptedSalt);

        entity.Password = encryptedPassword;
        entity.PasswordSalt = encryptedSalt;
    }
```

Which sweetly and simply applies my encryption to what ever was typed into the form prior to save being clicked, then refreshes the form to show the encrypted password and salt.

What I may do, is make the actual password read-only, and have a pop up to enter the plain text password, so there's no confusion, but for now this solves my problem.

@Chris Cook - thanks for your suggestion, it's given me a little more to explore (I really don't do much with LightSwitch to be honest) and new exploration of things is always interesting.  If you have any comments on how I solved this, I'd still be interested in hearing the pro's and cons.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use your Password field's Custom Validation method along the following lines:

```
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class User
    {
        partial void Password_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
        {
            this.Password = YourEncryptFunction(this.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

As you're using the Silverlight client, this validate method will run on both the client and server tiers.

If you need to force your code to only runs on the server tier (maybe because it's not supported in the realms of Silverlight :-) you'll need to wrap your code in a conditional compilation directive as follows:

```
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class User
    {
        partial void Password_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
        {
#if !SILVERLIGHT
            this.Password = YourEncryptFunction(this.Password);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks chris, I'll have a look at that later today, at the moment I've found some UserUpdate events in the the actual data tier that look promising.  I'm using CryptSharp for the encryption so I've had to give up trying to add this at the UI level as Silverlight chokes on the Library

Comment: Hi chris, I've added my own answer, still be interested in your feedback though as you've obviously done more with LS than I have.  I spend most of my time in frontend and web land.